# Symmetries for Julia sets of perturbations of polynomial maps

Tags: complex-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

This is a naive question. Consider the 
[Julia sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set)
of the map
$$ z \mapsto z^n + \lambda / z^k $$
with $z,\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, and the exponents $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$.
For example, for $n=k=3$, here are three Julia sets depictions for three 
different (relatively small) $\lambda$'s:

---

[image: z^3 & lambdas]

          

<sup>L-to-R:    $\lambda=0.2-0.1 i$;   $\lambda=2-i$;    $\lambda=0.07-0.5i$.</sup>

---

There is obvious hexagonal symmetry independent of $\lambda$. My question is:

> ***Q***. Given $n$ and $k$, are the symmetries of the Julia sets of this map,
>   for relatively small $\lambda$, known?
>   Should they always have $(n+k)$-gon-like symmetries?

I can imagine that many details of these maps are unknown, but perhaps at this high-level viewpoint, the gross structure of the Julia sets is known?
So for $n=4$ and $k=5$, should we expect to see nonagonal symmetries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Let $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/(k+n)}$. Then $f(\zeta^j z)=\zeta^{nj}f(z)$. Iterating this, the orbit of $\zeta^j z$ agrees with the orbit of $z$ up to multiplying by powers of $\zeta$. In particular, $z$ lies in the Julia set if and only if $\zeta z$ lies in the Julia set.

Comment: Thank you! ${}$